# knockout observableArray performance

Tags: javascript, performance, knockout.js

How to add all values to `observableArray` in one time? Adding values in loop works very slow in my case. Here is jsfiddle example.
[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gNJN5/113/)

Comment: i have one note about the adding items to an array performance issue that you should use array_name[array_name.length-1] = your item; this line is faster than push method

Comment: i think so see this article 
http://www.scottlogic.co.uk/2010/10/javascript-array-performance/

and sorry i have mistaken its array_name[array_name.length] = your item

Comment: this one can be useful also 

http://news.qooxdoo.org/javascript-array-performance-oddities-characteristics

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since you're clearing out the entire observable array, one way you can accomplish this is:

```
var viewModel = {
    name: "base",   
    addingValue:new ko.observable(),
    someArr: new ko.observableArray(["123","432","sdafasd","xrere"]),
    add: function()
    {
        this.someArr.push(this.addingValue());
    },
    updateSomeArr:function()
    {
        var temp = [];

        for(var i=0;i<5;i++)
        {
            temp.push("555565");
        }

        this.someArr(temp);
    }
}
```

Comment: No problem.  There is also a way to "turn off" the observing behavior, update your model, and then turn it back on--but I can't seem to find the page for it.

Comment: using array_name[array_name.length-1]=item; is faster than push method

Comment: @James D'Angelo: i found method ko.utils.unwrapObservable but cannt find how "turn on" observable behavior

Comment: I'll keep looking for a code sample.  If I find it, I'll add it to my answer.

Answer (score 16):

```
var myArray = ko.observableArray([]);
var valuesToInsert = [1,2,3];
myArray.push.apply(myArray, valuesToInsert);
```

that's it

Comment: Still do not understand why the most elegant and correct answer was downvoted :). Would be grateful for an explanation.

Comment: This is really the best approach to push all the items to an array at once.Here is a post on its usage http://www.knockmeout.net/2012/04/knockoutjs-performance-gotcha.html

Comment: @Akshat Thank you! After two successive downvotes of my answer I started thinking nobody who read it actually try to learn javascript :). Thanks again.

Comment: actually you shouldn't push apply to ObservableArray but to the underlying array. If you see what ObservableArray's push does here http://www.knockmeout.net/2012/04/knockoutjs-performance-gotcha.html you will see that actually your approach is firing many times the valueHasMutated which would be the same as pushing inside a loop and performance wide is bad. JD Courtoy responce is the right one!

Comment: @GeorgeMavritsakis Well, actually yes. I do see what push method does. And I do NOT see valueHasMutated firing many times with the code I suggested :).

Comment: @GeorgeMavritsakis I can even go as far as to insert logging statements into the valueHasMutated to ensure that what I am saying is true. Then could YOU please take the time to see what really happens. Just a simple task. Instead of pointing to some article that, who knows, maybe you did not understand properly :). Thanks.

Comment: Having read the linked article in it's entirety (array.push != array.push.apply) I can only say that @AGS is indeed correct, and illustrated in the article's JSFiddle.

Answer (score 3):

There is already a selected answer, but I thought that the following would help.  You can disable the observing behavior by executing your observable array to get the underlying array implementation:

```
var underlyingArray = viewModel.someArr();
```

You can then add items to `underlyingArray` without firing off `someArr` events.  Once you're done adding items, call:

```
viewModel.someArr.valueHasMutated();
```

This will cause the event to fire notifying all observables dependent on viewModel.someArr().